# How to take hidden input from inside option in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

Due to some requirement, I have to take a **hidden input field inside option tag of select element**. The problem I'm facing is, when the selected value is displayed, it's displayed with prefix `>`.

Here's my code:

```html
<form action="Action.java">
  <select name="cars">
    <option value="car1" <input type="hidden" id="hidden" value="c1">>CAR1</option>
    <option value="car2">CAR2</option>
    <option value="car3">CAR3</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Can anyone help me fix this issue?

Comment: That doesn't make any sense... It's not valid HTML.

Comment: It doesn't even made sense as an independent hidden input, it has no name.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the requirements that force you to do this? Seems like a [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) presented that way.

Comment: If you explain your requirement then we can tell you how to do it correctly, because what you have above is just plain wrong.

Comment: So is there any way to store c1 in some variable only when car1 is displayed?

Comment: @RAS — Why do you want to "store c1 in some variable"? What are you actually trying to achieve. You are still firmly in x-y territory.

Comment: @RAS why do u want to use c1 and want to hide?

Comment: I want to use it later when the form is submitted. But it should be present only when car1 option is displayed. To reproduce the issue easily, I have posted minimal code. In actual, car1 option is displayed based on some complex condition.

Comment: "I want to use it later" — For what? In JavaScript? In the server side code? What isn't `car1` enough to determine whatever it is you want to use `c1` for?

Comment: So would this work?  Remove the input from the option (as it should be) and have it with no value, but if you select CAR1 then it populates the hidden input with c1.  If you pick another option then it empties the hidden input value.

Comment: Yes, for javascript & for server side code both.

Comment: @Archer, what if car1 is displayed by default?

Comment: Then populate the hidden field by default as well

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do. For that purpose only, I cannot write the condition anywhere else & I have to take it with option tag.

Comment: You CANNOT do it within the option tag, as you have tried, which is why everyone is asking you to explain your requirement, rather than your proposed solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104298/discussion-between-ras-and-archer).

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, this line:

```
 <option value="car1" <input type="hidden" id="hidden" value="c1">>CAR1</option>
```

isn't valid html. Your browser is closing your optinput™ - and is then seeing an extra '>'

You could do this sort of thing (untested code):

```
 <form id="my_select">
   <select name="cars">
     <option value="car1">CAR1</option>
     <option value="car2">CAR2</option>
     <option value="car3">CAR3</option>
   </select>
   <input type="hidden" id="hidden" value="">
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

 <script>
 $("#my_select").change(function() {
   var str = "";
   $("select option:selected").each(function() {
    str += $(this).text() + " ";
   });
   $('#hidden').val(str);
 }).change();
 </script>
```

However, AND I CANT STRESS THIS ENOUGH: Don't.

Whatever your reason for needing to set that hidden field - do it in you back end code i.e (psuedo)

```
 if (cars === car1) {
   c1 = true
 }
```

But do you really need to set it?

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you have the emphatic "Don't"?